# Why did the same code about datetime display differently in text and SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

My method has two steps, in order to trace log, I record the time when each step is finished. The code looks like this:

```
//both time are the same 
private void TestDateTime() {
    AddNum(1,3);
    var step1FinishedTime = DateTime.Now;
    RecordToSqlTable(step1FinishedTime);
    AddNum(2,3)  
    var step2FinishedTime = DateTime.Now;
    RecordToSqlTable(step2FinishedTime);
}
```

I find that `step1FinishedTime` and `step2FinishedTime` are always the same value. So I try to make the thread sleep for some time. I find that they are always the same value too when only sleeping 1 milliseconds. By I add 100 milliseconds, the result is OK, they are different.

Even more surprising is when show the datetime in text using `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH：mm：ss：ffff")` will always be different.

```
//when sleep value is 1 are the same ,but 100 are different.
private void TestDateTime() {
     AddNum(1,3);
     var step1FinishedTime = DateTime.Now;
     RecordToSqlTable(step1FinishedTime);

     //some time for sleep   
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     AddNum(2,3)  

     var step2FinishedTime = DateTime.Now;
     RecordToSqlTable(step2FinishedTime);
}
```

The SQL result in the table are: `2014-08-05 23:13:03.853` and `2014-08-05 23:13:03.843`

Write time in text:

```
WriteText("Step1 finished at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH：mm：ss：ffff"));
Thread.Sleep(10);
WriteText("Step2 finished at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH：mm：ss：ffff"));
```

The text result are:

```
Step1 finished at: 2014-08-05 23:13：56：4365
Step2 finished at: 2014-08-05 23：12：56：4465
```

Why 1 and 100 has the different result? Why show the datetime in text are always different?

Comment: Don't expect windows to accurately track microseconds, it doesn't over open APIs to maintain compatibility with badly written programs from years ago.

Comment: You save steponefinished to a var, but you are printing out datetime.now in your output. Did you want to print out the datetime from the sql?

Comment: @scragar, the question is that I sleep 1 milliseconds the `DateTime.Now` seems not changed in sql-server table.And sleep 100 milliseconds the `DateTime.Now` seems changed in sql-server table.This is incredible.

Comment: What datatype are you using in your db, `datetime` or `datetime2`? If you're really worried about milliseconds (can't imagine why you would care about it in logging), datetime2 is more accurate.  If you're using `datetime`, SQL Server is going to do some rounding.

Comment: @KevinCook,I have the question when insert the time to the table in sql server,I read the table and see the problem,so I try to print out them directly from `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @Andrew,I use `datatime`.May be I should use `datatime2`.For examle,My method has two steps,I must get the result from the log.This result is related to the implementation of the sequence of events.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.100%29.aspx): DATETIME is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.

Comment: So if .853 != .843 but somehow that is not as good as .4456 != .4356?  I don't see the problem here, especially since both are different in the 100ths column. Is it because you don't like the rounding to 3 values rather than 4?

Comment: @KevinCook,sleep more time(100 instead of 1),my method will be more slowly.Especially when the program loop is called hundreds of times.So sleep 1 milliseconds may be OK,but 100 milliseconds seems not good.

Comment: So lets say you have 2 users on your system and both click save at the same time, are you expecting the datetime to be unique? If you are attempting to use a datetime as a unique index of some sort, you've already lost, it's a terrible practice that I see people attempt to use and it only ends in failure. Make an identity field to use with your datetime and use the identity to order your data instead.

Comment: @KevinCook,I think the sql server will have a order event handling mechanism or will deadlock.

Comment: Actually no, the datetimes can be the same, on a 400 TPS (transactions per second) system I used to work on, I would see it all the time, the granularity of the datetime isn't precise enough to use as a unique. The thought of introducing sleeps on a process just to create a unique identifier is even worse.  Imagine if your boss knew that you were actually slowing down processing because you couldn't figure out a simple way to make records unique (aka identity) that any DBA should understand, you'd be out the door and others would fix your code the right way.